# Ubuntu 20.04: stuck in emergency mode

Tags: boot, dual-boot, mount

Tried unmounting the disk by using 'sudo umount /dev/sda10/' but it doesn't work. Shows target is busy. Please help.

P.S: I have tried almost all the things available on the following links and nothing works.
[[Stuck in emergency mode and nothing works?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/960790/stuck-in-emergency-mode-and-nothing-works][1])

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7878707/how-to-unmount-a-busy-device][2]

[[How do I find out which process is preventing a umount?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11713/how-do-i-find-out-which-process-is-preventing-a-umount][3])

Answer (score 1):

try
`mount -a` 
`exit`
this helped me to get out of the emergency mode, but since this can only be a temporary solution, to get rid of the issue you'll have to format the partition which is causing the error by inspecting  journalctl -xb ,fstab (home partition had issue in my case)

Answer (score 0):

The following two links worked for me eventually after a day's hard work. Followed the first link till the second last step and then went ahead with the code on the github link. All the best!

https://medium.com/@nehamuthiyan/getting-out-of-the-emergency-mode-in-ubuntu-818180ce3940

https://github.com/trezcan/rpi-emergency-mode/blob/master/pi-corrupt-fix.sh

Comment: if possible kindly post a summary of what you from the links that got your system working again so the answer would still be available if the links are no longer available